# C++ namespace vs. iOS framework

Tags: c++, ios, frameworks, namespaces

I'm trying to understand namespaces a little better in C++. My first object oriented language is Objective-C so I compare other languages to it. It seems to me that C++ namespaces are similar to iOS frameworks like UIKit and Foundation. Which are files containing lists of other header files. I would also like to know if C++ namespaces are similar to C# and/or Java namespaces. I know of only one difference that C++ namespace has is the use of the (::) notation vs. the (.) notation in C# and Java. I also know that (unlike Objective-C) you can use the name of a namespace to call its class and function: like "System.Console.WriteLine()" or "std::cout". I appreciate any advice. Thanks

Comment: Will let other go into detail, my quick answer is they are not the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A C++ namespace is just that: something that separates names of one kind from names of another kind. The key point of a namespace is to avoid "name collisions" - two functions or variables having the same name, and thus the compiler/linker not knowing which one you mean.

A framework is a set of functions and/or objects that allow you to perform some partiuclar (set of) task(s). It could be:

- UI framework that helps you do menus, windows and dialog boxes.
- compiler framework that helps if you want to build a compiler.
- a framework for doing linear algebra.
- connect to a database-engine and formulate SQL queries.
- webtoolkit for building applications that talk to websites or displays webpages.

and millions of other things.

A framework typically is implemented inside a namespace, to avoid it colliding with other parts of your code or some other framework.

The standard C++ library is implemented in the `std` namespace, it is not strictly speaking a framework, but rather a collection of basic functionality that most applications will need in some way.

This is a pretty simplified view, as a complete descriptions of the two concepts is probably a few days worth of effort...

Comment: C and Objective-C doesn't support namespaces in the C++ sense, which is why iOS framework components come prefixed with a prefix specific for each framework. In this way, two names which would otherwise collide (e.g. Image) can be specified with respect to each framework. A real example is UIImage (in UIKit), CGImage (in CoreGraphics) and CAImage (in CoreImage).

In Java, namespaces correspond to "packages".

Comment: @mtroad packages are also not namespaces, in that they carry other baggage that a namespace does not.

Comment: @Yakk, good point. I meant that packages can prevent namespace collisions like namespaces in C++.